# Objectify filter on List of references in reference

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using GAE with Objectify and have entities as below:

```
@Entity
class LevelOne {
    @Id
    Long id;
    @Index
    @Load
    Ref<LevelTwo> two;
}

@Entity
class LevelTwo {
    @Id
    Long id;
    @Index
    List<Ref<LevelThree>> threes;
}

@Entity
class LevelThree {
    @Id
    Long id;
}
```

I want to find all `LevelOne`s that have a `LevelTwo` which contains a `LevelThree`

I use the query :

```
ofy().load().type(LevelOne.class).filter("two.threes", keyOfThree).list();
```

But I get no results. I get from the documentation on wiki that I should be expecting results if I don't use `Ref`s and Embed the complete entities, but the redundancy would get scary!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google App Engine's datastore does not perform joins. `Ref<?>`s are key references to foreign entities. You can't filter across references.

You can, however, create a synthetic index field in your LevelOne object and fill it (perhaps in an @OnSave method) with whatever data you wish - including data in other entities. However, as with denormalization in general, you'll have to be careful about how data is updated.